# Splitting of short exact sequence over a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homology-cohomology, tensor-products

Suppose that $S \subset R$ is a ring extension, and $T$ is a flat extension of $R$. Consider an exact sequence of $R$-modules:
$$
0\to X_1\to X_2\to X_3\to 0,
$$
which splits as a sequence of $S$-modules. Under what conditions on the extension $S \subset R$ and the module $T$ one can ensure that the induced sequence $$
0\to T\otimes_R X_1\to T\otimes_RX_2\to T\otimes_R X_3\to 0,
$$
also splits as a sequence of $S$-modules?

Some conceivable conditions include: $S$ being semisimple; $S=R$; and $T$ being a finitely generated projective $R$-module. Are there any other noteworthy cases?